# C++ Equivalent of ROSBag Code

Tags: c++, rosbag

[image: Rosanswers logo]

What is the C++ equivalent of "rewriting bag", given in the [cookbook](http://www.ros.org/wiki/rosbag/Cookbook)?

I want to process a particular topic from a rosbag file and write the others unchanged to a new bagfile. Any help would be appreciated.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/39409/c++-equivalent-of-rosbag-code/) by [Ankush](https://answers.ros.org/users/2890/ankush/) on ROS Answers with karma: 75 on 2012-07-20

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This code should work:

```
rosbag::Bag input("input.bag");
rosbag::Bag output("output.bag", rosbag::bagmode::Write);
rosbag::View topic_view(input, rosbag::TopicQuery("topic_to_reqrite"));

BOOST_FOREACH(rosbag::MessageInstance const message, topic_view) {
  output.write(message.getTopic(), message.getTime(), message, message.getConnectionHeader()); 
}
```

For more information on the API functions, have a look at the [API docs](http://ros.org/doc/electric/api/rosbag/html/c++/).

---

Originally posted by [Lorenz](https://answers.ros.org/users/21/lorenz/) with karma: 22731 on 2012-07-20

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 4

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Ankush](https://answers.ros.org/users/2890/ankush/) on 2012-07-21**:
Thank you, again! It is not very clear from the APIs that rosbag::write takes a MessageInstance as an argument.

**Comment by [Lorenz](https://answers.ros.org/users/21/lorenz/) on 2012-07-21**:
Well, I didn't try it out but I expect it to work because the MessageInstance has all the required traits defined to be serializable.

**Comment by [Ankush](https://answers.ros.org/users/2890/ankush/) on 2012-07-22**:
Just tried it out, it works. Thanks.